# In select cities or selected cities?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The original question is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57905/is-there-a-difference-between-select-and-selected) but it's still unclear to me.

> We have branches in **select** cities.
>   
>  We have branches in **selected** cities.

**My homework:** I asked this to a person who's master in English. He suggested this -

> Use 'select' when things are **really outstanding and very very unique**. *The metro rail in India is available in **select** cities.* Rest for everything, it's 'selected' especially discounted items and/or outlets of any brand in cities and towns.

By placing *'branches' in select cities the brand did nothing to the cities and there's no city with *very unique* quality in this matter. It'll be **'selected cities'**. Had it been the Olympic Committee's matter, we would have said, "They organize the event in **select** countries."

Clarification with references and examples please.

Comment: I think that person is right. The word "select" can be adj. besides v. As an adjective, it means "carefully chosen from a larger number as being the best or most valuable." Or, in short, something very outstanding.

Comment: I don't think *select* is appropriate in "[Volcanoes erupt] in select countries of the world".  I think *select* in this sense means "chosen in preference to others" or "of particular quality or excellence" (quoted from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/select)).  In particular, I think it's odd because the eruption of volcanoes is a natural phenomenon--it's not something that people select.

Comment: +1 and @snailboat, agreed. But then what about the latter example? The Olympic one? What's the ultimate answer?

Comment: Maulik, I'm in agreement with @snailboat on this one. As for your Olympics example, honestly I don't think either sounds right. The Olympics are only ever in one country at any given time. An example of how we use *select* in this manner: "The new product will be featured in select stores around the country!" Meaning that of the total stores that exist, a certain number (definitely >1) will house the product. So it doesn't make sense in the case of the Olympics. I might say something like "The Olympics are hosted in a different country each time they take place." I wouldn't use either here.

Comment: Agree with everyone on *volcano* but then let's focus on the question and not on my homework. My bad, I got it wrong. When use *select* and not *selected*?

Comment: Changed the example. Now it's okay I guess.

Answer (score 2):

They don't mean the same thing. They're not the same part of speech.

[*Select*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/select) as an adjective has a different meaning from [*selected*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/select).

First of all, I've got to say that I agree with the comments you've gotten so far, in that *select countries* **does not** work well with *volcanoes*. In fact, I actually find it to be crude.

Second,*select* does mean special, but *countries* aren't really special for having a natural disaster occur on their soil. It's not something fortunate.

Often, in the US, you'll hear *opening soon in select cities,* in reference to film releases. In that context, it means specially selected cities. It also can indicate a limited, small-market film release. And it's fine to use it that way. But I would **not** recommend saying something like ***the bombings*** occurred in **select cities**. Select has a positive connotation.

As for *selected*, it's the past tense of the verb form of *select*, meaning *to pick* or *to choose*. So if you say, *branches opening soon in selected cities*, you mean to say that these locations were hand-picked. It doesn't have to be hand-picked; items can be selected by machines too.

If *selected* items are on sale, then they were *picked*, *chosen*, or *designated* by management. You're referring to the selection (noun) process.

If *select* items are on sale, then there's something special, unique, or valuable about those items. Here, *select* is modifying the noun *items*. It's not referring to the process of selection, but they may be items you'd very much like to *select* (verb meaning choose).

> By placing *'branches'* in select cities the brand did nothing to the
>   cities and there's no city with very unique quality in this matter.
>   It'll be 'selected cities'.

This can actually be either one. With *opening branches in **select** cities*, it means they were selected because there is something unique about them. Maybe they're unsaturated markets, or maybe they were chosen because the business thought they'd be more profitable in those cities. If they're opening in *selected cities*, that just means that the branch locations have already been selected.

> Had it been the Olympic Committee's matter, we would have said, "They
>   organize the event in select countries."

Actually, they organize the events in ***the selected city***. At the same time, the IOC chooses from *select cities*.

Answer (score 1):

**"select "**as an adjective =a select group of people or things is **a small** **special group** that has been **carefully chosen** .

**"selected "** as an adjective =carefully chosen **from among a group** of **similar people or things** .